# Jetpack Compose AndroidView call Update

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Changing the state in the following way can work just fine

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CustomView() {

    val selectedItem = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        factory = { context ->
            CustomView(context).apply {
                myView.setOnClickListener {
                    selectedItem.value = 1
                }
            }
        },
        update = { view ->
            view.coordinator.selectedItem = selectedItem.value
        }
    )
}
```

What if I want to make a call?

Update the value by calling, not by changing the state

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CustomView() {

    val selectedItem = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    
    // I need to call some methods like below, but I can't get cropLayoutView
    // cropLayoutView.flipImageHorizontally()
    // cropLayoutView.flipImageVertically()
    // cropLayoutView.rotateClockwise()
    // val bitmap = cropLayoutView.croppedImage


    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        factory = { context ->
            CustomView(context).apply {
                myView.setOnClickListener {
                    selectedItem.value = 1
                }
            }
        },
        update = { view ->
            // How to make a call here?
            view.setCoordinator()
        }
    )
}
```

What if I want to make a call?

Update the value by calling, not by changing the state

Comment: The update is a normal lambda/callback that receives as the parameter an instance of the inflated view of your view type so you can make a call normally from it. So if your view class `CustomView` contains a public `fun setCoordinator()` then the call from you example should work. What issue or error are you seeing? Please post a snippet of code that shows the `setCoordinator()` method/function inside your view class `CustomView`.

Comment: @Ma3x Thank you for your comment, but it didn't solve my problem, because I didn't express it clearly, I updated the comment of the second code, can you take a look

Comment: Well, my comment was not supposed to solve your problem since I did not offer any solutions. In the comment I was asking for further clarification of your problem and I suggested that you show us the code inside your actual view (not the composable code, because that we can already see above). Now you mentioned that you "can't access `cropLayoutView`", but you did not say where in your code you keep a reference to `cropLayoutView` and why you can't access it. So we are still stuck, where nobody can help you with your question because it is unclear what exactly are you asking.

Comment: @Ma3X The documentation says: [Best practice is to construct views in the AndroidView factory. Do not save or remember direct references to views outside of AndroidView . ] https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#views-in-compose

Comment: @Ma3x This is what bothers me, it can't be called without a reference. At the same time, I can't show the method to be called, because it is an SDK and cannot be modified.

Comment: Correct, you should not keep the reference outside. But the update method passes you that reference every time it runs. And it runs after every state change so based on state you do whatever changes and calls you want to do on the view. But it is still unclear from your code where do you get the `cropLayoutView` from, because your code is constructing a `CustomView` and not, let's say, a `CropLayoutView`. Also if any parts are from an SDK post their full package and class names. Is the `cropLayoutView` a view class from an SDK? If so, can you post its full package name or a link to its docs?

Comment: If you are trying to use compose without using state you are doing it wrong. What you should do is update whatever in state. That will recompose and when it recomposes the update method will call. There you can put whatever logic you need to call your view.